# shows me long number in float type columns on table

Tags: html, sql-server

I create a procedure who send me an email, but i get wrong & long numbers in
the columns t, S, Tr. Do i need to casting this columns?

```
DECLARE @table  NVARCHAR(MAX) ;

SET @table =
N'<H1>some Report</H1>' +
N'<table style="width:100%">' +
N'<tr><th>D</th><th>Date</th>' +
N'<th>t</th><th>S</th><th>Tr</th>' +
N'<th>M</th></tr>' +
CAST ((SELECT td=[D],'',td=[D],'',td=round([Tr],0),'',td=round([S],0),'',td=[T],'',td=[M]
FROM [tblDrtrtrttgt]
WHERE  [p] >  dateadd (dd, -3, getdate()) 
order BY [S] desc
FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE 
) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) +
N'</table>' ;

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @recipients='someemail@gmail.com',
@subject = 'EmailofWork',
@body = @table,
@body_format = 'HTML' ;
```

The number in the table columns:
7.740000000000000e+003  1.525855000000000e+006  8.778700000000000e+004  3.029000000000000e+005

Comment: I must admit I never generated HTML from SQL server so I'm not sure but did you get the chance to see the generated HTML ? I have the feeling it might be a possible source for the problem

Comment: surely it would be better/possible to leave that html to the frontend to render rather than generate it in SQL?

Comment: this is what i get:
7.740000000000000e+003 1.525855000000000e+006 8.778700000000000e+004 3.029000000000000e+005

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you thought, casting should help.

Try something like this for your inner SELECT;

```
SELECT 
    td=[Description],
    '',
    td=convert(nvarchar(32), [Date], 102),
    '',
    td=cast(cast(round([Transactions],0) as int) as nvarchar(32)),
    '',
    td=cast(cast(round([Sales],0) as int) as nvarchar(32)),
    '',
    td=[Traffic],
    '',
    td=[Members]
FROM 
    [ffb].[dbo].[tblDashboard]
WHERE  
    [Updated] >  dateadd (dd, -3, getdate()) 
order BY 
    [Sales] desc
FOR XML 
    PATH('tr'), TYPE
```

See the MSDN documentation for [Cast and Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187928(v=sql.120).aspx) for help on these functions.

Hope this helps.

Rhys